# How can I call a method after a property changes in another class?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been trying to figure this one out for a while and I feel like I'm close to a solution, but that I'm missing some crucial bit of information. I'm hoping someone here can help point me in the right direction.

I'm writing a program to track weight and center of gravity for an assembly. There are four main classes that I've got:

1. BasicPart: Defines part properties that are independent of location (part number, volume, density, mass)
2. DetailedPart: A subclass of BasicPart that also contains location-based information (for example, CG location)
3. StdPartLibrary: Has only one property (a List object) and a few methods for things like saving/loading the basic part information to/from a file
4. MassModel: Has only one property (a List object) and a few methods for things like calculating the assembly's CG location

The user interface is a WPF form with, among other things, a datagrid showing the StdPartLibrary data and a table based on MassModel data showing the assembly's total mass and CG information. And I've implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on the BasicPart class so the datagrid will automatically recalcualte mass, volume, and/or density when the user changes anything in the table.

**But here's my problem:**

I can't figure out a way to update the table to automatically recalculate the total mass and CG location when the user updates data in the datagrid. Right now, I have a button that the user has to press in order to update the total mass and CG location information and that does the job. But I'm perseverating on this now and really want to figure this out.

From what I've been reading, it sounds like I need to somehow subscribe to the PropertyChangedEventHandler in BasicPart but I can't seem to figure out exactly how or where I would implement that. Any advice?

**ANSWER**

So it turns out that I'm an idiot. As Steve Byrne pointed out in the comments, I just needed to run my code to update the mass properties in the CurrentCellChanged event of the DataGrid. Thanks!

Comment: Can u post some code it will be more helpful to understand the problem an d is ur application using mvvm

Comment: so u wana do something like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55055841/how-to-call-a-viewmodel-method-from-another-class/55056086#55056086) let me know if there is more

Comment: @SteveByrne I tried that first. I used the CellEditEnding event on the DataGrid but that seems to execute before the properties were changed.

Comment: @Steve is the item source for DataGrid is `PartsList `  and the user edit some thing in grid u need need update that object is that right?

Comment: @Avinash No, the item source for DataGrid is the Library property in StdPartLibrary. And when the user makes a change in the DataGrid, Library is updated. That part I already have taken care of. The problem is automatically running the UpdateModelFromLibrary method in the MassModel class when Library is updated.

Comment: @SteveByrne ... you've GOT to be kidding me! Haha that's exactly where it needed to go. I can't believe I spent the last few days trying to do this the hard way :) Thanks!

Comment: just to leave it here, in [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/) there is extension method for INPC: `object.WhenAnyValue(x => x.PropertyToWatch)` - it allows you design data flows with Rx

Comment: @Steve, or steve Byrne please post your resolution to this as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's the basics, the `CellEditEnd` event fires between the content being saved in the data grid and after the users tries to stop editing the cell, the event can be cancelled to force the users to continue editing and thus does not commit (save) changes until the event has ended [source from docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.celleditending?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Because of this, you need to use another event, such as: [this event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.currentcellchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) `CurrentCellChanged` which will be fired after the cell is changed (committed/saved) but doesn't tell you which cell was changed Scottlogic.com supplies the example code below to combine `CurrentCellChanged` and `CellEditEnd` to both get the cell being edited, and fire after the event is fired:

```
private DataRowView rowBeingEdited = null;

private void dataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender,
                                  DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView rowView = e.Row.Item as DataRowView;
    rowBeingEdited = rowView;
}

private void dataGrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rowBeingEdited != null)
    {
        rowBeingEdited.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

[(Code's source, from blog.scottlogic.com posted by Colin E.)](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2009/01/21/wpf-datagrid-committing-changes-cell-by-cell.html)

Finally, there is another more complex solution, which would be to force a data commit to the cells by calling

```
  grid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);
```

(A full tutorial, and the original code can be found [here](http://codefluff.blogspot.com/2010/05/commiting-bound-cell-changes.html))

and then running your method now that the data has been committed.